# download excel template file to browser in angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-file-upload

i did try to download excel template file in angular6 using spring boot. in rest api file is getting download properly but when integrate rest api with angular  excel file is not getting download. Please any one can help

From angular to api is calling very fine

servivce.ts file

```
 download(data){
    const REQUEST_PARAMS=new HttpParams().set('fileName',data.fileName);
    const REQUEST_URI='/downloadTemplate'; 
    // don't have any issue with url as eddit by me
     return this.http.get(REQUEST_URI,{
        params:REQUEST_PARAMS,
        responseType:'arraybuffer'
      })
    }
```

component file

```
download(){
    this.fileName='download.xlsx';
    const EXT=this.fileName.substr(this.fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    this.service.download({'fileName': this.fileName})
   .subscribe(response=>{
    saveAs(new Blob([response], {type:'application/vnc.openxmlformats-        officedocumnet.spreadsheetxml.sheet'}), this.fileName);
   })
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: @AdritaSharma Thanks for your response. Working your solution as expected

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `{ responseType: 'blob' }`

Try like this:

service.ts

```
download(data){
    return  this.http.get(REQUEST_URI, { responseType: 'blob' })
}
```

component.ts

```
this.service.download({'fileName': this.fileName})
.subscribe(response=> {
    saveAs(response, this.fileName);
})
```